# What is the lowest level at which I can maximize my stats in Elephant Quest?

Tags: elephant-quest

In the interests of completing the game as quickly as possible, I'm curious to know: what is the lowest level at which I can maximise all my stats? What stat upgrade pathway do I have to take in order for this to happen?